# How do I connect an armature to a model?

Tags: mesh, rigging

So, I got a model of a woman from the internet, she's pretty high poly and she wasn't rigged in the first place, but I thought it won't be a big deal as I know how to rig. Then I opened the model in Blender, rigged her and tried to connect the mesh and the armature and nothing happened, they both connected in the way that they were on the same layer but armature moved by itself without the model. I have no idea what am I doing wrong, can someone help me out?

Comment: if you are using 'vertex groups' in the armature modifier, you'll have to define those vertex groups (named after the bones) on the mesh (with proper weights). Alternatively, the area of influence of the bones is too small

Comment: I have no idea what you just said(I'm sorry)

Comment: I think you should upload your blend file, in hope to have more concrete help here. Preferably use this link to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I thought you gave me a link for another blender-blog where I can ask this question, I only now realized what you meant, here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4688" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4688/)